# How can i convert YCbCr to BGR24 using ImageISharp

Tags: c#, yuv, imagesharp, color-conversion, ycbcr

I get an image in IntPtr or an array of bytes in the YUV420 color space. How can I use ImageSharp to convert an image to BGR4 color space?

I can't find conversion examples anywhere with imageSharp . Therefore I use other library for conversion. But I have problems with her

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560918/yuv420-to-rgb-conversion

Comment: You can have a look here: https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.ColorSpaces.Conversion.html.